# Why does the DHT11 have a non-connected pin?

Tags: sensor

I am using a [DHT11](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/758/DHT11-Technical-Data-Sheet-Translated-Version-1143054.pdf) sensor. I was looking at the pin configuration, and I don't understand why a pin is not-connected but still there.

It has 4 pins:

1. Vcc
2. Signal pin
3. Nc (not connected)
4. Gnd

Why is there a NC pin? If we can't use that pin, why is it there?

Answer (score 4):

There are many possible reasons for an NC pin.
It is very common that components has one or several NC pins.

Some possible reasons are:

- Use of a standard package that has more pins than needed
- To remain pin compatible with some other part
- Pins used for production testing by component manufacturer, not to be used outside of the factory
- Pins used only for mechanical reasons to provide rigidity once mounted on a PCB.

Answer (score 1):

Many integrated circuit components come in standard packages with a preset number of pins. If the circuit schematic that is contained inside of the package doesn't use a number of those pins, they are simply indicated to be left disconnected as "No Connect".